# Who inflects "innit"?

Tags: vocabulary, abbreviations, negation

I'm quite surprised there doesn't seem to be a question about this yet. Depending on where you hail from, you've probably heard the word *innit,* an abbreviation of *isn't it* or *ain't it*. You may also have heard it used as a placeholder for any negative tag question, such as *isn't he* or *don't you,* much like the French *n'est-ce pas*.

I get how *innit* could be understood as something like *isn't that so,* but I can't quite bring myself to use it that way. So what to do instead? I inflect it:

- Aren't I → areni ['ar(ɛ)naɪ]
- Aren't you → arencha* ['ar(ɛ)nʧə]
- Aren't we → arenwe* ['ar(ɛ)nwɪ]
- Isn't he → innhe* [ɪni]
- Isn't she → innshe [ɪnʃi]
- Aren't they → arenthey* [ar(ɛ)n(ð)ɛɪ]
- Don't I → dunni ['dʌnaɪ]
- Don't you → doncha* ['dəʊnʧə]
- Don't we → donwe ['dəʊ(n)wɪ]
- Doesn't he → dunnhe* ['dʌni]
- Doesn't she → dunnshe ['dʌnʃi]
- Don't they → dunney ['dʌnɛɪ]

Those marked with asterisks are those for which I can find references via Google. I found it interesting that third-person female forms (*-she*) haven't shown up at all, though I excluded spellings such as *dontshe* for obvious reasons.

Granted, I don't actually use these all that often, and I'm quite uncertain of how to spell some of them (I keep thinking that the *-i* ones should end in *-igh*), so I don't really have a perfect way to search for usage. I don't really know which modals to exclude, either, as pronunciation changes in running speech are commonplace.

So where might I find pronunciation, usage, and spelling information on these words?

Comment: The spellings of these words are what appear on the lefthand side of each list item.  The "official" spelling of *innit* would also be "isn't it". (The thing that is special about UK *innit* is when it is used.)  None of these others are considered standard by anyone.  They reflect normal phonological reduction that occurs in high frequency phrases like this.  Other examples include "whatcha doin (what are you doing)", "c'mere (come here)", "gimme that (give me that)", "put'm-up (put them up)", and so on.  Are you looking for a guide on how the more common reductions work?

Comment: Interesting question. As a non-native speaker, I don't feel the need to inflect *innit* at all. I just store it in the exact same part of my brain as the proverbial Swiss *oddr* (or the German *oder*), the French *n'est-ce pas* you mentioned, and the Russian *не так ли*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: They may be nonstandard, but I think they're common enough to undergo more pronounced reduction than other phrases involving "do" and "be", and if that's the case, I'm just looking for resources to satisfy my curiosity about it.

Comment: Is "inflect" the right word for this context?

Comment: @Jon Purdy: My point is that, as nonstandard processes, there is no place to find, say, spelling information on these words.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: The only ones I do not use out of this list are: *don't/doesn't we/she/they*.  All the rest are used fairly commonly in my neck of the woods, especially the *-cha* endings for *you*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: With the modern prevalence of written language in colloquial form, complete with contractions, pronunciation alterations, et al.  I think that spelling information for these sort of words should start coming in, to standardise what exists.

Comment: @RegDwight: Same here. Or the Japanese *ne* (ね) or *na* (な).

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: I was uncertain about it, but couldn't come up with anything better.

Comment: @RegDwight, @Robusto - or the American "right?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Britain, '*innit*' is now used in street language as a catch-all tag question, exactly like *n'est-ce pas*. The whole point of it is that is not inflected, but used for everything, and that's what raises some people's hackles so much. The fact that it is regularly parodied on a couple of TV comedies has probably only increased its popularity with the young.

It was in the news lately when actress Emma Thompson told a group of school kids that using slang words like ‘innit?’ and ‘like’ made them sound stupid.

Professor David Crystal has a short piece about it on the [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1453_uptodate3/page8.shtml) website, and I think Michael Quinion has something at [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/), but I can't seem to find it.

What you've done really is simply to slur standard question tags, that's another matter - but the point of *innit* (in the UK at least) is that it has taken on an uninflected life of its own.