# "Is it" South Africa only

Tags: british-english, south-african-english

I don't know if it is still in vogue but ten years ago in South Africa the phrase "Is it?" was common.  It could be used as a response to almost any statement. Is it (ha ha) unique to South Africa or of Brit origin?
examples:
"I'm going to the movies" - "Is it?"
"Can't find my keys." -"Is it?"
"He's dead you know." - "Is it?"

Comment: Not used here in the US.

Comment: Here in California, at least in certain circles, 'Oh really?' serves the same purpose. "I was stuck in traffic for two hours this morning". - "Oh really?"

Comment: Sounds like a geographically and temporally localised "catchphrase" to me, [innit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/who-inflects-innit)?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not used here in Australia. Beginner English learners sometimes use it as a much simplified inquiry into veracity of any statement, before they're able to put together more complex questions.